# Which version of Jruby support IPv6?

Tags: ruby, jruby, ipv6

We are now using JRuby 1.7.x, and it support IPv6.

I would like to know where can I find explicitly describe Jruby for each version if it support IPv6 or not.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think that this is connected to JRuby. From what I read it's about the JVM you are running on. The Java Release 1.5.0, which is already some years old, states that Java supports IPv6 transparently, so JRuby should do it too:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/net/ipv6_guide/index.html#using

Comment: Isn't it rather the library and not the JVM which has to support IPv6?

Comment: @glglgl it's probably both

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out already, JRuby relies on underlying technologies (JVM, Ruby libraries, as well as IPv6 name servers, etc.) to support IPv6. You can also quickly check if you've got everything you need:

```
$ jruby -S irb
jruby-1.7.1 :001 > RUBY_DESCRIPTION
 => "jruby 1.7.1 (1.9.3p327) 2012-12-20 fffffff on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.7.0_10-b18 [darwin-x86_64]" 
jruby-1.7.1 :002 > require 'resolv'
 => true 
jruby-1.7.1 :003 > Resolv.getname('2001:4860:4860::8888')
 => "google-public-dns-a.google.com"
```